# Is this a known format, or a custom one?

Tags: json, serialization

maybe some of you know the game Overwatch, they released a Workshop feature recently which allows people to "write" scripts. (You actually just have many dropdowns).

The game allows you to copy and paste rules, when you copy them they are copied into your normal clipboard and I'm wondering if the clipboard-format is a common/known or a custom one.
My Goal is to be able to load the script in a nodejs application but before I start writing my own parser I wanted to check if this is actually necessary.

I think the Format looks JSON-ish but not 100% I tried to google for "Json like formats" but I did not find anything related to that.

```
rule("INITIALIZE REAPER")
{
    event
    {
        Ongoing - Each Player;
        All;
        Reaper;
    }

    conditions
    {
        Has Spawned(Event Player) == True;
    }

    actions
    {
        Create HUD Text(Event Player, Add(Index Of Array Value(Player Variable(Event Player, A), Last Of(Player Variable(Event Player,
            A))), 1), Null, Null, Top, 0, Red, White, White, Visible To and String);
        Create Effect(Event Player, Ring, Red, Position Of(Event Player), 20, Visible To Position and Radius);
        Set Damage Dealt(Event Player, 50);
        Set Max Health(Event Player, 160);
        Damage(Event Player, Event Player, 50);
        Create HUD Text(Event Player, Player Variable(Event Player, C), Null, Null, Right, 0, White, White, White, Visible To and String);
        Chase Player Variable At Rate(Event Player, C, 0, 1, Destination and Rate);
        Set Healing Dealt(Event Player, 5);
        Set Damage Received(Event Player, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't close to 100%.

Comment: That looks about 0% JSON

Comment: That's just content they put on the clipboard as text. It doesn't even look 1% *JSON-ish*. It bears no resemblance to JSON whatsoever.

Comment: It looks Json-Ish for me because of  the Key-Value kind of structure. Like rule would be the key and event,conditions, and actions would be "sub-keys" and the rest like a list, just my interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

This format is a custom format, it is quite similar to other formats but it is custom, some people are now working in making a transpiler for this format. (a transpiler is like a compiler except it compiles code from one language to another, unlike compilers which compile to assembly)